# cd into a directory without knowing its name in bash

Tags: bash, cd

If I know there will be a single folder inside a directory, but I do not know it's name, is there a simple way in bash to go into it? If I wanted to do a check to make sure a folder exists within the current directory, can that be done?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If there is **only one sub-directory** inside your current path then you can use this glob pattern to do `cd`:

```
cd */
```

Pattern `*/` matches all the sub-directories from current path and since there is only one so this `cd` will just change directory to single sub-directory.

Comment: PS: If there are more than one directory then `cd */` will change to first sub-directory.